# How to hide control center in ionic/cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm running into an issue because of a UX decision of my app.

I have a footer bar on some screens, that require a swipe up to open the details of the user profile. But in iOS when you swipe from the bottom of screen to up, it happens to the control center come up in front of my app.

But I saw some applications that when you swipe up that way, the control center just prompt a pointer, then you swipe up again that pointer to the control center come up. This is comum mainly in games, but one example is the YouTube app.

I want to know if its possible to do that kind of behavior in my app, through Cordova or Ionic.

Here some screens of my app to get better context of what I'm talking about.

[image: Img 1] [image: Img 2]

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior you're talking about, you need to add the statusbar plugin and set the status bar to hidden.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`

Then add the following to your apps Info.plist file:

`<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>`

It may still override your bottom swipe however.  Good Luck!